# $.each only affects the first element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looping through all the elements of the class, I see the code below only affecting the first element in the array yet the console log logs every one of them.

```
del = $('<img class="ui-hintAdmin-delete" src="/images/close.png"/>')

$('.ui-hint').each(function(){
                   console.log($(this));
                   if ($(this + ':has(.ui-hintAdmin-delete)').length == 0) {
                       $(this).append(del);
                   }
           });
```

The elements are all very simple divs with only text inside them. They all do not have the element of the class i am looking for in my if statement, double checked that. Tried altering the statement (using `has()`, using `children()`, etc). Guess i'm missing something very simple here, haha.

Will apperciate input.

Comment: 'this' is an object here, not a string that you could use in your selector string.

Replace 
$(this + ':has(.ui-hintAdmin-delete)')
 with
$(this).find('.ui-hintAdmin-delete')

Comment: @eggward, do you mean `$(this).filter(':has(.ui-hintAdmin-delete)')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is (also if `del` should be a string, if it is a dom element reference then you need to clone it before appending)

```
$('.ui-hint').not(':has(.ui-hintAdmin-delete)').append(function(){
    //you need to clone del else the same dom reference will be moved around instead of adding new elements to each hint
    return del.clone()
});
```

Comment: NB: You don't need the function. You can just use `.append(del.clone())`, you only really need to use a function when you need to access the index. [See docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-functionindex--html)

Comment: @DerFlatulator if you use `del.clone()` then the cloning will happen only once.... you need to clone it for every `hint` element without the del element

Comment: Yes, an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('.ui-hint:not(:has(.ui-hintAdmin-delete))').append(del);
```

without even using the each loop here. As jquery code will internally loop through all the descendant of the `ui-hint` class element and append the `del` element only to the descendant not having any `.ui-hintAdmin-delete` elements.

Answer (score 1):

While it would probably help to see your HTML as well, try changing your conditional to

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-hintAdmin-delete')) {
    $(this).append(del);
}
```